# Add dynamic GoogleMap Marker after getting response from Rest API

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How can do dynamic google marker after get the coordinates from server i am fetching latitude and longitude from REST API

my **showMarker** function is given below:

```
private func showMarker(_ lat: String, _ lng: String, _ description: String){

        let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = Double(lat) ?? 0.00
        let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = Double(lng) ?? 0.00

        print("Latitude: \(latitude), Longitude: \(longitude)")


        let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
        marker.title = ""
        marker.map = self.mapView

    }
```

If the below code run in ViewDidLoad() that's working fine

```
    self.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 6.244880, longitude: 7.001920, zoom: 10.0)
    mapView.camera = self.camera
    mapView.animate(toZoom: 10.0)

    self.mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.view.bounds, camera: self.camera)
```

But when i called them after the above code after the showMarker function then camera object get nil

I just want to add the marker after fetching the data through rest api

Comment: You are showing the code in `viewDidLoad` that worked. Where's the code that didn't work?

Comment: i want to show marker not in viewDidLoad() i want to show it on after my restAPI Call